# Laravel Model relation

Tags: laravel

I want to make relation between 2 tables by third table like:

1. Player can be signed to 1 team only.
2. Team can have many players.

## current relations

`player model`

```
public function teams()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'team_players', 'team_id', 'player_id');
    }
```

`team model`

```
public function players()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class, 'team_players', 'team_id', 'player_id');
    }
```

### more...

currently 1 player can be select for unlimited teams at the same time, what I want is 1 player = 1 team only. and if I detached player from that team then be able to sign it to another team.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you've a pivot table `team_players` which contains at least `team_players` and `team_id` field. With that on mind, you should inverse the foreign keys in `team` model that you've currently, for example, change it to this:

```php
public function players()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Player::class,
        'team_players',
        'player_id', // foreign key of this model
        'team_id' // foreign key of joining model
    );
}
```

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you
>   are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the
>   foreign key name of the model that you are joining to. [Check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your case you need an one-to-many relationship between team and players. A team can "hasMany" many players while a player "belongsTo" a team.
So for the team model

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Player::class);
}
```

and for the player model

```
public function team()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
```

In terms of database tables you only need a "team_id" field in the players table to hold the relationship.